# IntelliJ extract data from sqlite database file?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, intellij-idea

I just started with sqlite and I stuck with a strange (maybe just for me) phenomenon. When I connect the testDB.db file in java, and make one or some query, the data and the table itself is disappearing. The consol said that SQL error or missing database, and when I check the database file in cmd, the situation is really that; there is no data in the file. Could anybody help me out with this basic problem? (I suppose that this is just because of the lack of my knowledge in this topic, but I'm open to new information)

```
public class jdbcTest{

public static void main(String[] strg) {

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Username\\Documents\\sqlite\\testDB");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.setQueryTimeout(30);

        //statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists person");
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from company");
        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.print("id = "+rs.getInt("id")+"   ");
            System.out.println("name = "+rs.getString("name"));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (connection!=null){
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't your connection string end with `testDB.db` ?

Comment: I've used that file too, but the same happend. The simple testDB file has been created in cmd with .save testDB command to save the database

Answer (score 0):

When opening a nonexistent database file, SQLite will happily create a new, empty one.

The file name you're giving to `getConnection` does not actually point to the database you saved.

Comment: Maybe I've found the problem's source. When I decomment the statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists person"); line (and change the person parameter to company (which is the only table in my db file), ), the SQL error or missing db message appears and from this point the table is gone from my file and make it empty (not just for the intellij but for the sqlite too)
But what's that line for and how could I use it to not kill my db?